# Batch won't detect negative variables

Tags: batch-file

So, I've been tinkering with this for a little while and I can't figure out why it won't work.

If negative 50 is less than 10, it should display "Good Job". However, it keeps outputting "fail". I did this with a few different batch scripts (i.e. without the gotos and without the "()"'s) to see if it was the way I was programming it, but apparently not. I'm at a complete loss here.

```
@echo off
set var=-50
if var LSS 10 (
    goto complete
    )
echo Fail.
pause > nul
:complete
echo Good job.
pause > nul
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is working as you intended.

```
@echo off
set var= -50
if /I %var% LSS 10 (
goto complete
)
echo Fail.
pause > nul
:complete
echo Good job.
pause > nul
```

Link: http://ss64.com/nt/if.html

You could also use `if [Variable] LSS 10`

Answer (score 0):

Var needs to be in % signs.

```
set var=-50
if %var% LSS 10 Echo Hi
```